# Regex extract text within a form

Tags: regex

I have a body of free text that roughly follows a form like this:

> Oracle Account #: 
>   Claim Judgement: 
>   Order Type:

And the free text looks like this

> Oracle Account #: 123456Claim Judgement: ApprovedOrder Type: FURN

What I was thinking I could do was use a regex looking for the first attribute "Oracle Account #:" then a section of text that wasn't in the corpus of form attributes, then end on anything in there. So it would look like

```
 'Oracle Account #:(?!Oracle Account #:|Claim Judgment:|Order Type:)(Oracle Account #:|Claim Judgment:|Order Type:)'
```

and then extract with just \1, however this fails to identify that sample I provided. Any idea how this might work?

Comment: You want the account number? `Oracle Account #: (\d+)`

Comment: That simply never matches like this is never going to match `(?!.).`

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you're trying to match/capture.

Comment: I'm trying to capture the account number, however it could be in basically any form not just numeric. The only certainty I have is that it will be followed by Claim Judgement or later on Order Type. My problem is that Claim Judgment could be misspelled so I can't just do (.*)Claim Judgement. That's why I want to check against the set of form options

Comment: It's going to be pretty tough to regex if you can't rely on the input. You'd have to figure out which misspellings you need to cover and add each to the regex. But then you're bound to miss one, and then nothing works.

Comment: It'd obviously be much better to have separate fields for each value, but presumably that's not possible.

Comment: An idea: replace all the known texts with some separator symbol (say, `§`) and then split with that char.